# extract number after specific of list string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, dataframe

I have this example dataset

```
No Text
1  {"duration_incoming_daytime": 6034, 
    "percent_incoming_daytime": 42.73, 
    "percent_other_calls": 42.73, 
    "total_calls": 110}
```

all I want is extract the number after specific string, "duration_incoming_daytime", "total_calls"
please, dont use str.split(), because my data isn't ordered like the example
so, it would be like this

```
No Text                                  duration_incoming_daytime   total_calls
1  {"duration_incoming_daytime": 6034,   6034                        110
    "percent_incoming_daytime": 42.73, 
    "percent_other_calls": 42.73, 
    "total_calls": 110}
```

Here's the example dataframe

```
import pandas as pd   
No = [1]   
Text = [{"duration_incoming_daytime": 6034, "percent_incoming_daytime": 42.73, "percent_other_calls": 42.73, "total_calls": 110}]   

df = pd.DataFrame({"No":No, "Text":Text})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JSON functions here, but given that the JSON is not nested, `str.extract` can also work:

```py
df["duration_incoming_daytime"] = df["No Text"].str.extract(r'"duration_incoming_daytime"\s*:\s*(\d+)', regex=True)
df["total_calls"] = df["No Text"].str.extract(r'"total_calls"\s*:\s*(\d+)', regex=True)
```